# How to set ASP.NET version for virtual directory in windows 7

Tags: iis-7

can anyone guide me how to set ASP.NET version for virtual directory in windows 7.
I am searching in IIS Manager, The UI of IIS Manager in Windows 7 is totally changed and I could not find it at all.

Answer (score 1):

.NET framework version is set on an Application Pool basis in IIS 7.